# How to make all of these small images stop shifting on resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have to make this map with all these location points on it. The map already had points on it, but they wanted a hover effect, so I had to recreate the points so they could have that effect and then layer them over the original ones. The issue is that when I resize (for some reason, only on the mobile screen size), they shift slightly to the left. Is there a way to fix this? Here are pictures of the changes as well as my code.

Ignore the ones in Brooklyn. I haven't done those.

100% zoom: [image]

150% zoom: [image]

My Code (ignore the lack of js. I got rid of it since it ostensibly doxxed these places):

```css
 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    /* This is for screens that are phone screen sizes */
    /* This code below is for the map */

#main_map_div{
    position: relative;
}

.map_point{
  position: absolute;
}


#map{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
}

.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}
    #brightside{
    top: -46vw;
    left: 33.2vw;
    width: 4vw;
}

  #cargo{
    top: 42.6vw;
    left: 29.1vw;
    width: 4.5vw;
}
  #achilles{
    top: 50.2vw;
    left: 28vw;
    width: 4.3vw;
}
  #do{
    top: 25.5vw;
    left: 46.8vw;
    width: 4vw;
}
 #monas{
    top: 25vw;
    left: 52vw;
    width: 4.1vw;
}
 #bohemia{
    top: 31vw;
    left: 49.4vw;
    width: 4vw;
}
 #cumming{
    top: 23.7vw;
    left: 57.9vw;
    width: 3.4vw;
}
 #fnj{
    top: 29.3vw;
    left: 55.8vw;
    width: 3.8vw;
}
#rebar{
    top: 30vw;
    left: 63.8vw;
    width: 3.7vw;
}
 
#turnmill{
    top: 23.2vw;
    left: 66.7vw;
    width: 3.6vw;
}
  
#silvana{
    top: 29.9vw;
    left: 71.6vw;
    width: 3.6vw;
}

#patrick{
    top: 25vw;
    left: 77vw;
    width: 3.5vw;
}
  
#elevenst{
    top: 23.7vw;
    left: 86.2vw;
    width: 3.7vw;
}

#bbh{
    top: 36.5vw;
    left: 84vw;
    width: 4vw;
}

#diwine{
    top: 38vw;
    left: 68vw;
    width: 4vw;
}

#dominie{
    top: 46vw;
    left: 68.8vw;
    width: 4vw;
}

#neirs{
    top: 54.5vw;
    left: 61.9vw;
    width: 4vw;
}

#sst{
    top: 67%;
    left: 53.2%;
    width: 4.2%;
}

#lobster{
    top: 67%;
    left: 46.5%;
    width: 4.2%;
}

#erdp{
    top: 62%;
    left: 40.5%;
    width: 4%;
}

#lowlands{
    top: 55%;
    left: 42.8%;
    width: 4%;
}

#wmc{
    top: 54%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 4%;
}

#metropolitan{
    top: 49%;
    left: 46.4%;
    width: 4%;
}

#ilporto{
    top: 55.5%;
    left: 56.2%;
    width: 4%;
}

#superfine{
    top: 50%;
    left: 53%;
    width: 4%;
}
  }
```

```html
<div id="map_main_div">
  <div id="info_card" class="hidden">
    <p id="title">Brightside Tavern</p>
    <p id="address">141 Bright St, Jersey City, 07302</p>
  </div>
  <img id="map_image" src="/s/map.png" />
  <img src="/s/brightside.png" id="brightside" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()"/>
  <img src="/s/cargo.png" id="cargo" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()"/>
  <img src="/s/achilles.png" id="achilles" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/do.png" id="do" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/monas.png" id="monas" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/bohemia.png" id="bohemia" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/cumming.png" id="cumming" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/fnj.png" id="fnj" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/rebar.png" id="rebar" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/turnmill.png" id="turnmill" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/silvana.png" id="silvana" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/patrick.png" id="patrick" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/elevenst.png" id="elevenst" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/erdp.png" id="erdp" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/lowlands.png" id="lowlands" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/metropolitan.png" id="metropolitan" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/lobster.png" id="lobster" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/wmc.png" id="wmc" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/superfine.png" id="superfine" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/ilporto.png" id="ilporto" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/sst.png" id="sst" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/diwine.png" id="diwine" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/neirs.png" id="neirs" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/dominies.png" id="dominie" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
  <img src="/s/bbh.png" id="bbh" class="map_point" onmouseover="showInfo(this)" onmouseout="hideInfo()" />
</div>
```

%, vw, vh, and px all created this moving issue. I'm not the best at CSS so I'm not really sure if using a different one will solve the issue or if something else will help it. I also will include the images themselves so you can try it out yourselves if that will help.

[image: Here's one of the points]
[image: Here's the map itself]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with mobile is that you can resize your image container without respecting the height/width ratio, if the height and width are not explicitly provided. The solution therefore consists of having a div container with your map as a background-image. This div must have explicit dimensions (for example --ratio:2; width:100vw; height: calc (100vw * --ratio);, of course the ratio is arbitrary here you will calculate it depending on your map dimensions). Then inside this container you position your logos relatively, in %.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything on the ratio property for CSS. Is the ratio value a variable stand-in to represent the number I'd put there? I found an aspect-ratio property that does a similar thing.

Comment: This was a variable, as an example! It's up to you to calculate this ratio, by calculating the height/width ratio

Comment: That's what I assumed. Unfortunately, I'm doing this on Square Space (that's where the site was being built already) and I can't seem to figure out how to get the div background image working, so I'm struggling to test this out. I tried it using calc as well as with the aspect-ratio feature built into CSS and in both cases, I had the same issue. Thank you for trying to help though!